# How to find the difference between two columns in a dataframe with either rows in the column have -ve and/or +ve values in Python

Tags: python

I have two columns (x & y) in a df with 4 row scenarios (+ve)-(+ve), (-ve)-(-ve), (+ve)-(-ve) and (-ve)-(+ve).

df

```
 x    y
 3    2
-4   -2
 2   -1
-6    1
```

I want to insert a third column z in the same df and the end result as shown below

df

```
 x    y    z
 3    2    1
-4   -2   -2
 2   -1    3
-6    1   -5
```

Comment: Why were last two rows being added instead of subtracted?

Comment: 1st row (+3) - (+2) = 1, 2nd row (-4) - (-2) = -2, 3rd row (+2) - (-1) = 3 and 4th row (-6) - (+1) = -7. I am trying to subtract x - y. Both x and y have -ve to +ve scale and I need the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x['z']=x.apply(lambda row: row[0]-row[1],axis=1)
```

[image]

passing axis=1 to apply() helps us to access all values of a row.

Comment: Question, what is "x"? column or df?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
df['z'] = df['x'] - df['y']
```

Comment: No, I tried df['z'] = df['x'] - df['y'], it only applies for the first row, rest of the rows result incorrect values.